# How to program Linux .dts device tree files?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm going to launch a Linux on my development board, and i need a dts file (device tree file) to describe the whole hardware. But I only know very little about the syntax of this file which is not enough to run Linux properly on the board.

What i know now are only how to describe a unit's interrupt number, frequency, address, parent-unit and its compatible driver type (as described below):

```
ps7_scuwdt_0: ps7-scuwdt@f8f00620 {
                        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-scuwdt-1.00.a";
                        device_type = "watchdog";
                        interrupt-parent = <&ps7_scugic_0>;
                        interrupts = < 1 14 769 >;
                        reg = < 0xf8f00620 0xe0 >;
                } ;
```

Other advanced usage or grammar is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at the dts of the board which most closely resembles your dev-board. Use that as a reference and make changes to the dts according to the differences between the reference board and your dev-board.

Also checkout the following :
 - [Device-tree Documentation project](http://elinux.org/Device-tree_documentation_project) at eLinux (has a vast collection of links to start reading).
 - [Series of articles](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1) on the basics of device tree.
 - [Walkthrough](http://elinux.org/images/4/48/Experiences_With_Device_Tree_Support_Development_For_ARM-Based_SOC%27s.pdf) of migrating to device-tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references. Unfortunately, the first one is broken. Is there any suitable replacement to it?

Comment: @rbrito Thanks for pointing out the dead-link. Removed it. Update link1 with a more comprehensive source that has grown over the past few months.

Answer (score 5):

**Minimal `reg` + `interrupt` example with QEMU virtual device**

Our example will add the following device tree node to the `versatilepb` device tree which QEMU will use due to `-M versatilepb`:

```
lkmc_platform_device@101e9000 {
    compatible = "lkmc_platform_device";
    reg = <0x101e9000 0x1000>;
    interrupts = <18>;
    interrupt-controller;
    #interrupt-cells = <2>;
    clocks = <&pclk>;
    clock-names = "apb_pclk";
    lkmc-asdf = <0x12345678>;
};
```

Then, by using a Linux kernel module to interact with the device, we will test the following DTS features:

- registers addresses
- IRQs
- read custom properties from the driver

These are the main components of the example:

- [Linux versatile `.dts` patch on Linux fork](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/361bb623671a52a36a077a6dd45843389a687a33/arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dts#L42)

  - `reg` and `interrupt` match numbers hard-coded in the QEMU versatile machine (which represents the SoC)
  - `compatible` matches the `platform_driver.name` in the kernel module, and informs the kernel which module will handle this device
  - we also pass a custom property to the driver: `lkmc-asdf = <0x12345678>;`, which is read with `of_property_read_u32`
  - the device tree is passed to QEMU's firmware with the `-dtb` argument
- QEMU fork:

  - [device](https://github.com/cirosantilli/qemu/blob/144ea94d710c666babd06ed733007377e132ed4a/hw/misc/lkmc_platform_device.c) that reads a register and generates interrupts
  - [insert device into `-M versatilepb`](https://github.com/cirosantilli/qemu/blob/144ea94d710c666babd06ed733007377e132ed4a/hw/arm/versatilepb.c#L302)
- [kernel module](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/05fa0105eaccf37d6a675f9b2bae833fd78d4270/kernel_module/platform_device.c) Writes to memory on probe to test things out, which also generates an IRQ.

Device trees have many more features that we haven't covered, but this example should get you started, and easily allow you to play around with any new features that come up.

Further resources:

- indispensable elinux tutorial: http://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage
- play around with `dtc` for purely syntaxical questions. E.g., it shows how nodes are simply merged by path: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375923/32558
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/what-is-a-device-tree-and-a-device-tree-blob

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a example and I will explain each one of them as below

```
auart0: serial@8006a000 {
compatible = "fsl,imx28-auart", "fsl,imx23-auart";
reg = <0x8006a000 0x2000>;
interrupts = <112>;
dmas = <&dma_apbx 8>, <&dma_apbx 9>;
dma-names = "rx", "tx";
};
```

Required properties: 
- compatible : Should be "fsl,-auart". The supported SoCs include
imx23 and imx28.
- reg : Address and length of the register set for the device
- interrupts : Should contain the auart interrupt numbers
- dmas: DMA specifier, consisting of a phandle to DMA controller node
and AUART DMA channel ID.
- dma-names: "rx" for RX channel, "tx" for TX channel.

Note: Each auart port should have an alias correctly numbered in "aliases"
node.
For more advance properties, please go to this link, it is very useful
[Device Tree Explanation](https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Complementary to the other answers:

Keep in mind, that there is also a section for devicetrees in the official kernel source under `root/Documentation/devicetree`(https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree?h=v5.2-rc5).