# Devicetree in embedded linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, device-tree

How can I convert platform specific file to device tree?.

I know theoretically about device tree.
Please explain how its works in raspberry pi board or any other boards.

Comment: Learn more about [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)

Comment: What is *platform specific file*? You mean the actual kernel platform data specific to each board or a custom vendor-specific file somehow describing your platform? Either you write a script to automate this or you do it manually (which should be faster). We won't explain *how it works* here... read the [device tree usage](http://www.devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage) and learn how it's used in the kernel (API in `drivers/of` and lots of device trees in `arch/arm/boot/dts` and `arch/powerpc/boot/dts`).

Comment: Maybe if you provide which file your looking to "convert" we can give you some hints.

Comment: ARM Linux kernels contain a lot of non-enumerable hardware and tend to have a board-file that does this programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

A device-tree is simply a data structure for describing the hardware present on a system. In the absence of device-tree, systems rely on *"board-files"*. These are C files with plenty of structures, each describing every individual hardware present on the system and also how they are connected.

> Porting of code from legacy *"board-files*" to device-tree **`dts`** files is currently an ongoing process across several platforms/devices based on the ARM architecture.

To do this one requires proper understanding of the

- platform/device hardware.
- structure of the board-file.
- structure of the dts file.

This answer should help you get started in **[preparing a device-tree `dts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17783206/319204)**.

Also there is an ongoing effort to migrate the raspberry-pi Linux-kernel to use device-tree. Take a look at the **[source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/wiki/Device-Tree-port)** and **[booting instructions](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/wiki/How-to-boot-using-device-tree)**.